# My first column of code in a simple console program (c++) ends up as my last column

Tags: c++, arrays

My first column should be 8 hashtags going down but that column ends up on the end. so now i have two columns of hashtags at the end of my code. Also the last printed character is a glitch character.

[pic](http://imgur.com/pSQcupT)

Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    unsigned char nip[8][8] = {
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}};

    for(int c = 0;c <= 2; )
    {
        for(int z = 0; z <= 7 ; cout << nip[c][z])
        {
            z++;
        }
        c++;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    Sleep(8000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the point of incrementing outside your for loops instead of placing them inside? it seems like unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current loop is pretty strange. Give this a shot instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    cout << nip[j][i];
  cout << "\n";
}
```

That will print what you want. Sorry i changed the indices to `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this:

```
for(int c = 0; c <= 7; c++)
{
    for(int z = 0; z <= 7 ; z++)
    {
       cout << nip[c][z];
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```